# Is it safe to store encryption key in android class file

Tags: android

I'm doing some simple encryption on the values of shared preference to hide my data structure from users. I made a AES key and saved it in my class file with other codes as plain text. How hard is it to for a user to find my key with a decompiler? should I save it to string.xml? is there any rule I should add to gradle to make it more secure? I want to make it secure while keeping it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's not secure. An apk file can be decompiled and all resources files can be read, also Strings kept in source files can be read pretty easily. You might use DexGuard and let it encrypt your key in the source file, but I would rather set up a web service that retrieves the key once it's running on a device. You can add more security to it, like a login for example. That way, it's only possible to get the key if you have access to a device with the app installed and logged in.

Comment: then the GCM token and other api keys in my xml is also insecure? anyone could steal my token/keys for his own use?

Answer (score 0):

try [facebook conceal](https://github.com/facebook/conceal) you can find furter documentation and download [here](http://facebook.github.io/conceal/documentation/) .